# Select range of years using singular date from one mysql table

Tags: mysql

I want to create an sql query that selects years after a particular date.

Essentially i have a table that has the date a person registered. i want all the dates (in years) from date of registration to today.

Example:
Person registered on March 31, 2013

Todays date is Sept. 9, 2016

Therefore the SQL query would return 
 2013, 2014, 2015 and 2016

how can i accomplish this?

Comment: If this data does not actually exist in your table, you may need to use a calendar table.

Answer (score 0):

You can pretty easily create a derived table with numbers.  Then you can do:

```
select year(t.date) + n.n
from (select 0 as n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all
      select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
     ) n join
     t
     on t.date >= date_sub(curdate(), interval n.n year);
```

Of course, you might need to extend the derived table if your data goes back farther in time.